# Sufficiency of KKT in nonconvex case

Tags: optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

For an optimization problem

$$
\begin{align}
 \min_{x} \quad & f(x)\\
 \nonumber \text{subject to } \quad & h(x) \le \vec 0\\
\quad & l(x)=\vec 0\\
\end{align}
$$

the four KKT conditions are

1. Stationarity: $\vec 0 = \nabla f(x) + u^T \nabla h(x) + v^T \nabla l(x)$
2. Complementary slackness: $u^T h(x) = 0$
3. Primal feasibility: $h(x) \leq \vec 0$ and $l(x) = \vec 0$
4. Dual feasibility: $u \geq \vec 0$

Under strong duality (Slater's condition),

$$\begin{align}
f(x^*)
& = \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) + u^{*T} h(x) + v^{*T} l(x)\tag{1}\label{1}\\
& \leq f(x^*) + u^{*T} h(x) + 0 \\
& \implies \\
0 & \leq u^{*T} h 
\end{align}$$

That is, $0 \leq u^T h$, and from primal and dual feasibility we know that $u^T h \leq 0$. So, complementary slackness is necessary for optimality under strong duality.

- Therefore, under strong duality, the complementary slackness condition is redundant. Is that correct?

Now, [these slides](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eggordon/10725-F12/slides/16-kkt.pdf) say that the KKT conditions are always *sufficient* for optimality (i.e., under both strong and weak duality). But in a situation where Slater's condition isn't satisfied, it's possible for there to be a duality gap. Then the equals sign in $(\ref{1})$ becomes $\geq$, and we no longer can guarantee complementary slackness ($0 \leq u^T h$). We might get "lucky" and discover an optimal solution by searching for $x, u,$ and $v$ that satisfy the KKT conditions; on the other hand, the optimal solution might be noncomplementary.

- What would be an example of a problem that fails Slater's condition, but does have a solution that satisfies the KKT conditions (and, by sufficiency, is optimal)?
- In problems with a duality gap, is there still a way to use the KKT complementary slackness condition? (Maybe we could take the duality gap $f^* - g^* = - u^T h$ as a measure of "noncomplementarity" and try to minimize it.)

Comment: Are you assuming the problem is convex?

Comment: @littleO Fixed the typo. And no.

Comment: I don't understand why the KKT conditions you give are those of your stated optimisation problem.  They look to me like the conditions for the following problem:
$$
\begin{align}
 \min_{x} \quad & f(x)\\
 \nonumber \text{subject to }
\quad & h(x)\le\vec 0\\
\quad & l(x)=\vec 0\\
\end{align}
$$ That is,  in the KKT conditions you appear to have replaced $\ g\ $ with $\ h\ $ and $\ h\ $ with $\ l\ $.

Comment: Their slide 10 doesn't make much sense to me. Why did they write that
$g(u^*, v^*) = f(x^*) + \sum \ldots + \sum \ldots$? By definition, $g(u^*,v^*) = \min_x L(x,u^*,v^*)$. Who said that $x^*$ is the minimizer? And it's pretty well-known that KKT conditions are **necessary** under mild conditions, but you need stronger conditions for sufficiency. Since they've written that they are "always sufficient", I suspect they have some additional assumptions.

Comment: One thing to be very careful about here is that in those notes, the KKT conditions involve the **subdifferentials** of the functions $f, g$, and $h$. For non-convex functions, this is different than the stationarity condition you have written which involves the gradients of the functions $f, g, h$. For non-convex functions, it is possible (and not unusual) for your condition 1 to be satisfied but for their condition involving subdifferentials to not be satisfied. I believe this helps answer @Dmitry 's question. Their condition 1 is equivalent to assuming $x$ minimizes $L(\cdot,u,v)$.

Comment: @littleO, do you mean that, by definition of subdifferential, **for all feasible $x$** we must have $f(x) - f(x_0) \ge \langle 0, x - x_0\rangle$? So the sufficiency becomes trivial simply because of stationarity?

Comment: For non-convex problems, the KKT conditions as you have written them are not sufficient to guarantee that $x$ is a minimizer for the primal problem. For example, $x$ could be a maximizer. The KKT conditions as you have written them are analogous to the optimality condition $\nabla f(x) = 0$ for unconstrained optimization problems. As we know, for unconstrained problems, the condition $\nabla f(x) = 0$ is necessary but not sufficient for $x$ to be a local minimizer of $f$ (assuming that $f$ is a differentiable function).

Comment: @dmitry Yeah, if $F:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ then to say that $z \in \partial F(x_0)$ means that $F(x) \geq F(x_0) + \langle z, x - x_0 \rangle$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$. So to say that $0 \in \partial F(x_0)$ means that $F(x) \geq F(x_0) + \langle 0, x - x_0 \rangle$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$, or in other words that $x_0$ is a global minimizer of $F$.

Comment: Here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4474706/prove-the-point-is-local-minimizer-given-that-kkt-and-licq-are-satisfied/4479312#4479312, I have discussed when KKT conditions are sufficient to reach local optimality. The assumptions are quite strong, as expected. After understanding the comments above, you can try to understand what I said.